# Chai test failure with arguments

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I can't seem to completely understand how to properly work with testing, specifically with Chai library. Or I might miss something from programming fundamentals, kinda confused.

Given test:

```
it("should check parameter type", function(){
    expect(testFunction(1)).to.throw(TypeError);
    expect(testFunction("test string")).to.throw(TypeError);
});
```

And this is a function I'm testing:

```
function testFunction(arg) {
    if (typeof arg === "number" || typeof arg === "string")
        throw new TypeError;
}
```

I was expecting for test to pass, but I'm just seeing that thrown error in the console:

```
TypeError: Test
    at Object.testFunction (index.js:10:19)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\index.spec.js:31:28)
```

Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `testFunction` is called and - if no error is thrown - the *result* is passed to `expect`. So, as an error is being thrown, `expect` is not called.

You need to pass a function to `expect` that will call `testFunction`:

```
it("should check parameter type", function(){
    expect(function () { testFunction(1); }).to.throw(TypeError);
    expect(function () { testFunction("test string"); }).to.throw(TypeError);
});
```

The `expect` implementation will see that it has been passed a function and will call it. It will then evaluate the expectations/assertions.

Comment: thanks, that's worked. Is it normal to throw TypeError in that kind of type checking? I mean if I would use that kind of logic in prod env (say based on node.js), will that cause the whole app to terminate?

Comment: Throwing a type error if an unexpected argument is received is appropriate; that's what the Node's [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) API does, for example. And if the error is unhandled, yes, the process will terminate.